# Display two different ValidationSummary controls on single view. Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, validationsummary

What I need to do if I want display two different ValidationSummary controls on my view?
First control is the control which display regular validation errors, it's simple. 
Second one is the ValidationSummary control which should contains warnings, but not errors.

To achieve this I tried to follow this steps:

1. Add new property to my ViewModel. The property implements INotifyDataErrorInfo interface and inherited from FrameworkElement.
2. Set ValidationSummarys' ***Target*** binding to the property.
3. When adding new warning to collection calling ErrorChange of the property.

But ValidationSummary do not show any warnings. Even do not subscribes to ErrorChange event of this property.

What I am doing wrong?